# Adding data to 2 Tables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to add 2 `UITableView`'s to my `UIViewController`. I need to add different data to these tables.

This is how i added the 2 tables (this code was added to the ViewDidLoad method)

```
self.tableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,140,292,250) style:UITableViewStylePlain] ;
self.tableView2 .dataSource = self;
self.tableView2 .delegate = self;
```

Then the other table

```
self.tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,100) style:UITableViewStylePlain] ;
self.tableView1 .dataSource = self;
self.tableView1 .delegate = self;
```

The number of sections defined as follows;

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView==tableView1) {
        return 12;
    } 
    else { return 10; }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    // ...... more code here
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {     
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Cells .... ";
    } 
    else{
        // the remaining code here.. i am populating the cell as in the previous `IF` condition.
    }
}
```

The problem is that, i am getting only the first Table fill and not the 2nd table. Why is this? and how can i solve this ?

**EDIT:
I also added the following code, hope it makes a change**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView==tableView1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (tableView==tableView2) { return 0; }
    else { return 0; }
}
```

Comment: How do u add the tableViews to the superview?

Comment: Well.. i did it according to the above code. and it gets displayed too. I can't populate it. Help required !

Comment: are sure sure you return anything in the else part ?

Comment: Yes i did, the same code inside the `if` condition, with different table names.

Comment: I added a new Code block to my question. hope it would help finding what went wrong

Comment: no sections for table view #2 == no cells.

Comment: Thank you, i am not using my Mac now. i will have to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to follow these steps in order to make the two table views having the same `delegate` and `dataSource`.

1. Set the `tag` property of your table views, and `#define` constants on the two values. This makes the code consistent.
2. In delegate and datasource methods you implement in your view controller subclass, test the `tag` property value against the constants you defined.
3. Don't return 0 section for a table view, it won't display any cell at all.

So, for example :

```
#define TV_ONE 1
#define TV_TW0 2

// setting the tag property
self.tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)
                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView1.tag = TV_ONE;
self.tableView1.dataSource = self;
self.tableView1.delegate = self;
// the same for tableView2 using TV_TWO

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView.tag == TV_ONE) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (tableView.tag == TV_TWO) {
        return 1; // at least one section
    }
    else { return 0; }
}
```